# Выполнить замену всех строк

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть скрипт, который находит нужные строки, после он должен найти каждую совпавшую строку в тексте, и в случае нахождения - заменить на другой текст:

Набросал такой код:

```
foreach ($a_links2 as & $value2) {
    echo $value2->src; //строки которые нужно заменить
    $text = str_replace($value2->src, "КАРТИНКА", $article['content']);
}

echo $text;
```

В итоге получается что заменяет только последнюю найденную строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий вариант, должен отработать правильно:

```
$text = $article['content'];
foreach ($a_links2 as & $value2) {
    $text = str_replace($value2->src, "КАРТИНКА", $text);
}
echo $text;
```

Comment: так мне не нужно по несколько раз выводить один и тот же текст. есть статья, в которой некоторое слова нужно заменить, эти слова ищем и заменяем. а вывести все нужно один раз.

Comment: @Денис пробуйте новый вариант

Comment: результат тот же...

Comment: Вы уверены что у вас не 1 совпадение? Я код проверял у себя, ввел случайные данные и всё работало, проверьте что у вас в переменных $value2->src и $text, может действительно 1 совпадение

Comment: проверял несколько раз. совпадение не одно. если делать как вы предлагали изначально, заменяет все что нужно, но при этом статью выводит несколько раз, и каждый раз с одной заменой(сразу первая строка заменена, потом вторая заменена, при этом первая уже не заменена). и тд.

Comment: @Денис это был первый вариант кода ,сейчас я другой код написал, он выводит только 1 раз текст сразу со всеми изменениями

Comment: прошу прощения. все работает. не заметил строку в **str_replace** что вы заменили. спасибо большое за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно, вы же указываете каждую итерацию $text = (Присвоить) а не добавить к существующей переменной.

```
 $text .= str_replace($value2->src, "КАРТИНКА", $article['content']);
```

Comment: заменяет теперь только первую строку